# How to get "onclick" after click on div in link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get "onclick" after click on div in link on jquery?

```
<a href="#">
   <img src="some.jpg" />
   <div class="cont" onclick="showDiv()"></div>
</a>
```

```css
img {
    position: relative;
}

.cont {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

I want that when you click on region ".cont"occurred an event that I can handle. I tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    function showDiv() { 
        alert("test"); 
    } 
});
```

my js

```
$('#tmp').justifiedGallery({
        rowHeight: 350,
        maxRowHeight: '100%'
    }).on('jg.complete', function () {
        $(this).find('a').colorbox({
            maxWidth : '90%',
            maxHeight : '90%',
            opacity : 0.2,
            transition : 'elastic',
            current : ''
        });
    });
```

Comment: did you tried anything so far?

Comment: What's the problem? you can call functions with onClick

Comment: Elaborate your problem please

Comment: yes, $(document).ready(function () {

    function showDiv() {
        alert("test");
    }
}); - not work

Comment: @deni5n post code in question not in comment

Comment: on 'a' already refers to the function:

Answer (score 1):

You defined the `showDiv()` function within the the document.ready handler, so it is out of scope of the `onclick` attribute. You need to define the function at the lower level:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showDiv() { 
            alert("test"); 
        } 

        $(document).ready(function() { 
            // jquery code here...
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

A better solution entirely would be to use Javascript to attach your events, as it is a better separation of concerns and removes the outdated `onclick` attribute:

```
<a href="#">
   <img src="some.jpg" />
   <div class="cont"></div>
</a>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.cont').click(function() {
        alert('test');
    });
});
```

Comment: tanks, 
I am doing  $(document).ready(function() {function showDiv() { } }); ((((

Answer (score 0):

You cant write a function like this in $(document).ready(function()

try this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".cont").click(function(){
            alert("test");
        });
    });
```

or

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
            showDiv();
        });
   function showDiv() { 
        alert("test"); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this.

The way I'd do this:

```
$('.cont').on('click', function(){
  alert('qwerty');
});
```

That way you wouldn't need the *onclick="showDiv()"* in your HTML which would make your HTML cleaner.

The way that uses you *onclick* of the element:

```
function showDiv(){
  alert('zxcvb');
}
```

[Sample at CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OMzLRB)